# system of linear equation: how to check if determined, underdetermined or incompatible?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How do I determine, if a system of linear equation is determined, underdetermined and incompatible?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#General_behavior

Comment: overdetermined means has no solutions, underdetermined means infinite solutions, incompatible i don't think i've heard.

Comment: When you learn to start solving systems you will learn how to see what happens. Different things happen depending on which method you use and there are plenty of methods to solve en with.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking whether a system

\begin{align}
Ax + By &= C \\
Dx + Ey &= F
\end{align}

has no, one, or infinitely many solutions?

Well, if that is the case, then think of the two (three, four, five etc.) equations as lines. If they are parallel (same slope) but have different $y-$intercepts, then they have no solutions; they will never intersect. If they are not parallel, then they have one solution (this works for two only. 3+ the equations have to be concurrent). If they have the same $y-$intercepts and the same slope, then they are the same line and so they have infinitely many solutions.